# Cipher decrypt returns NULL - AndroidSDK 28 and above

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null, nullreferenceexception

RSAData.java

```
public byte[] decryptData(byte[] data) {
    try {
        byte[] decrypted = decryptCipher.doFinal(data);
        return decrypted;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is working well with other android versions, but it doesn't work for Android 28 and above. This method returns NULL and data is coming accurately till here. Please help!

Comment: So you have an exception. You did not tell the exception message. Why? Or did you say that doFinal() returns null?

Comment: @blackapps the exception is - invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Comment: Ok. So `decryptCipher` is the null object. Dont use it if it is null. Check for null before use.

Comment: @blackapps
decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
 decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

Comment: If getIntance() returned null then decryptCipher will be null. So check if it is null after that statement.

Comment: @blackapps yes, I think android is no more using the BC or the algorithm provider. I tried removing it, but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: Check for null in decryptData function.

Comment: @blackapps - you're right, it is in fact null.

Comment: and then I receive this exception - com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to decrypt block

Comment: You can tell that. But what can i do?

Comment: @blackapps - nothing, thanks for your help & time.